# Windows opens .py file with C:\Python27\Python.exe despite rebinding Python.File

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I followed Python's official [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html) to make .py file executable, i.e. adding .py to $PATHEXT and bind Python.File to "C:\Python27\Python.exe" "%1" %*. The result was fine:

```
>assoc .py
.py=Python.File
>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python27\Python.exe" "%1" %*
```

I recently installed virtualenv and hope to run a django project in a virtual environment called env1. The path to env1 is: "D:\env1". when I entered env1 in cmd, and try to execute django-admin.py directly, an ImportError Exception is thrown. I figured this is because windows invoked my default python interpreter(c:\Python27\python.exe) under which django is not installed. So I tried the following:

```
ftype Python.File="D:\env1\Scripts\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

The command executed successfully. However, the behaviour of executing .py file didn't change at all. Either double clicking the file or executing it directly by filename in cmd, c:\python27\python.exe was always invoked, as was shown from Task Manager.

At this point I can only think of that this problem is related to some windows settings and has nothing to do with virtualenv. Please help to get the binding work properly, Thanks!

Comment: You're running this in virtualenv right? It's been a LONG time, but doesn't venv give you a way to "activate" certain environments? Isn't that what you're really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another key is overriding the key set by `ftype`. You can search for the key using
[Registry Editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136393)
also known as `regedit`. Search for

```
C:\Python27\Python.exe
```

Comment: I find one in the Default key under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command`, and then I find a DWORD called `Progid` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice`, of which the value is `Application\python.exe`. How do I make change of these?

Comment: @Benny it shouldnt hurt to just delete both keys; if you are nervous you can back them up first.